# JS: When making a closure, how does the inner function access the outer function argument if I'm not storing as a variable?

Tags: javascript, closures

I don't know how these closures 2 accomplish the same thing. 
I understand how example 1 below would work since the variable `foo` is storing the value of the argument but what I can not understand is that taking away the variable in example 2 and just accessing the outer argument directly from the inner func, how does it have any reference to that?

```js
//ex1:
function firstex1(x) {

    let foo = x;
       console.log(foo)
     
    function second() {
     return foo + 100
  
       }

    return second
    }

console.log("Example 1:  "+ firstex1(1)());
//ex:2 


    function firstex2(x) {
 
       console.log(x)
     
    function second() {
     return x + 100
  
       }

    return second
    }
console.log("Example 2:  "+ firstex2(1)());
```

Comment: Function parameters are essentially locally scoped variables.

Comment: got it.  I actually always stored them as variables for readability.  Is that bad practice?

Comment: *"for readability."* ? How does `let foo = x` make it more readable?

Comment: @JohnNada There's absolutely no point to it. It doesn't make things any more readable, it makes it more confusing. A reader will wonder why you need a separate variable -- are you planning on modifying one while retaining the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example 2 a argument x is passed to the outer function. Inside the outer function every entity has access to x as it's scope is covered in the full code block of that function. When an inner function tries to access that x it can do it easily as it has access to that scope because it itself is present in that scope.
It's just like when you declare a global variable and try to access it inside a function. The function has access to all the global variables.

```js
    var count=0;
    function a()
    {
    console.log(count++)
    }
    
    a();
```

The above will return count+1 and so will

```js
 function first(x) {
    
       console.log(x)
    
       function second() {
        return x + 100
    
       }
    
       return second
    }
    
    console.log(first(1)());
```